# Can't get value using function, returns blank value

Tags: html, ajax, variables, jquery

I want it to show the div relating to the tab if it = 1, or hide it if it = 0.

Script:

```
function blah(){
 loadtab('a');
 loadtab('b');
 loadtab('c');
}

var page = cheese

function loadtab(tab){
    $('#'+tab).hide();
    $('#'+tab).load("devices/" + page + ".html " + "#" + tab);
        var tabcontent = $("#"+tab).text();
        alert(tab); //works
        alert(tabcontent); //doesn't
        if (tabcontent == "1"){
            $('#'+tab).show();
        }
        else{
            $('#'+tab).hide();
        }
}
```

*variable defined in previous code

HTML on cheese.html:

```
<div id="a">0</div>
<div id="b">0</div>
<div id="c">1</div>
```

Alerting tab gives a, b and c in seperate alerts. Alerting tabcontent gives a blank alert. Why is this?

Comment: Because load("devices/" + [variable]* + ".html " + "#" + tab) sets empty value? Also, you should use .html(), not .text().

Comment: @TomasVoracek I've made it clearer on what I want to do, will it still set it empty?

Comment: .text() should work fine if it's a div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're getting the text before the load method finishes populating the tab. Try executing your code in the callback of `.load`.

```
$('#'+tab).load("devices/" + page + ".html " + "#" + tab, function(){ 
   var tabcontent = $("#"+tab).text();
    alert(tab); //works
    alert(tabcontent); //doesn't
    if (tabcontent == "1"){
        $('#'+tab).show();
    }
    else{
        $('#'+tab).hide();
    }
});
```

On a side note, you should probably cache `$('#'+tab)` as you use it pretty often in that function.

To cache your selector, simply do this.

```
 var $tab = $('#'+tab);  // store your jQuery object into a variable 
 $tab.hide();
 $tab.load("devices/" + page + ".html " + "#" + tab);
     var tabcontent = $tab.text();
     alert(tab); //works
     alert(tabcontent); //doesn't
     if (tabcontent == "1"){
         $tab.show();
     }
     else{
         $tab.hide();
     }
```

It just improves performance as jQuery doesn't have to keep searching the DOM for the tab, you simply keep  reference to it in another variable at the start of your function.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. What would caching help with this? What exactly does it do? It's going to be loading different htmls with different numbers values for a b and c.

Comment: @Supertod Caching helps because jquery selectors are not exactly the most optimized in comparison to using native js to find dom elements. If you are going to constantly need to pull up that element, might as well store it in memory so you don't have to repeat the process and waste processing time during critical code sections where performance is vital.

Answer (score 0):

try to do this:

```
function loadtab(tab){
    $('#'+tab).hide();
    $('#'+tab).load("devices/" + page + ".html " + "#" + tab, function() {
        var tabcontent = $("#"+tab).text();
        alert(tab); //works
        alert(tabcontent); //doesn't
        if (tabcontent == "1"){
            $('#'+tab).show();
        }
        else{
            $('#'+tab).hide();
        }
    });
}
```